# Python3 - how to change volume of a sound in pygame mixer

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame, volume

i am making a game in pygame and there is one sound which when i play using

```
import pygame
retro = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/retro.wav")
retro.play()
```

it almost kills my ears it's too loud, is there a way to change the volume of the sound i am playing...

Thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume) to set the volume, from 0.0 to 1.0 where higher is louder.

```py
import pygame
retro = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/retro.wav")
retro.set_volume(1.0)
retro.play()
```